# What test can I use for contingency table bigger than 2x2 when some levels are n <5?

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, fishers-exact-test, yates-correction

I've been trying my luck with my data, consisting in 2 vectors of 3 levels each. I got a 3x3 contingency table, and the details of the code (in R) I've used are in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76417224/why-is-r-not-performing-yates-correction.

The thing is, some values of my data are really low, like 0 for some levels.
I'll copy some of the code used:

```
x <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "3", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "3", "2", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "2")

y <- c("1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "2", "2", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "2", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "1", NA, 
"2", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", 
"2", "1", "1", "2", "2", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "1", "1", "1", 
NA, "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "1", 
"1", "1", "1")
```

```
x
  1   2   3 

121  35   2



y

1   2  NA   3

120  36   2   0


Warning: Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
    Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  df$eq_5d_movilidad and df$eq_5d_mov_fin
X-squared = 34.842, df = 2, p-value = 2.718e-08
```

Edit1:
Edited output, as I've selected as levels of each vector ("1","2","3"). Also I tried making a contingency table with package "gmodels":

```
   Cell Contents
|-------------------------|
|                       N |
| Chi-square contribution |
|           N / Row Total |
|           N / Col Total |
|         N / Table Total |
|-------------------------|

 
Total Observations in Table:  158 

 
             | y 
           x |         1 |         2 | Row Total | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           1 |       106 |        15 |       121 | 
             |     1.691 |     5.731 |           | 
             |     0.876 |     0.124 |     0.766 | 
             |     0.869 |     0.417 |           | 
             |     0.671 |     0.095 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           2 |        16 |        19 |        35 | 
             |     4.498 |    15.243 |           | 
             |     0.457 |     0.543 |     0.222 | 
             |     0.131 |     0.528 |           | 
             |     0.101 |     0.120 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
           3 |         0 |         2 |         2 | 
             |     1.544 |     5.233 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     1.000 |     0.013 | 
             |     0.000 |     0.056 |           | 
             |     0.000 |     0.013 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
Column Total |       122 |        36 |       158 | 
             |     0.772 |     0.228 |           | 
-------------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
```

The thing is, I want to know if there is any correction to use when the data is as low in size across a level.

Thanks!

Comment: I cannot see any "3x3" tables anywhere in this post: could you clarify what you mean by that?

Comment: I mean, a column full of 0  on the variable y could be made, as there is some observations in x that are = 3, but none in y. Technically it is a table 2x3, but the problem  remains in a 2x3 table aswell.

Comment: When an entire column or row of zeros occurs, it's not relevant to the analysis of the table.  That is why it is so confusing to refer to a $3\times 3$ table while presenting only $2\times 3$ tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The warning not to trust the chi-sq test itself should not be trusted. If we focus on the pure purpose of testing, that is to infer whether there is row/column dependence in the contingency table, then you'll find in many cases the Pearson chi-square test of dependence is well calibrated. Consider that the test statistic is calculated as:

$$ X^2 = \sum_{i,j} (O_{ij} - E_{ij})^2 / E_{ij}$$

Where it gets hairy in my opinion concerns the actual interpretation of the $p$-value or the confidence interval for the odds ratio(s) which depend much more critically on these terms having well behaved distributions.

Consider a few simple methods exist to address this "problem":

- the first, the Yates continuity correction, is already applied by specifying "correct=T". (Correct=F does not mean incorrect).
- An interesting feature R added to `chisq.test`: "simulate p-values" which could provide exact distributional estimates of the test statistic under the null even when cell counts are sparse.
- Another interesting correction is the Agresti Coulli method which simply adds 1 to each cell, thus exchanging an unbiased but highly variable estimator, with one that is biased but far better behaved.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to AdamO's solution, you can also use Fisher's exact test, either with or without simulation of p values.

On your data I found:

fisher.test(x,y,simulate.p.value = TRUE) #0.0004998
fisher.test(x,y) # p = 5.305e-08
chisq.test(x,y) # p =  2.718e-08
chisq.test(x,y,simulate.p.value = TRUE) # p = 0.0004998